# Display content based on date and time

Tags: php, date, time

I'm needing to display content during a certain day and time.

I have a script which I'm using at the moment which displays content depending on the day of the week but need to extend this to display content between two sets of hours so content on a Monday between 12am and 5pm then between 5pm and 11.59pm and the same for each day of the week.

```
<?php 
if( date( 'w' ) == 0 ) { 
?> 
<div>Write what you need to show here on Sunday</div> 
<? 
} 
if( date( 'w' ) == 1 ) { 
?> 
<div>Write what you need to show here on Monday</div>
<? 
} 
?> 
<? 
if( date( 'w' ) == 2 ) { 
?> 
<div>Write what you need to show here on Tuesday</div>
<? 
} 
?> 
<? 
if( date( 'w' ) == 3 ) { 
?> 
<div>Write what you need to show here on Wednesday</div> 
<? 
} 
?> 
<? 
if( date( 'w' ) == 4 ) { 
?> 
<div>Write what you need to show here on Thursday</div> 
<? 
} 
?> 
<? 
if( date( 'w' ) == 5 ) { 
?> 
<div>Write what you need to show here on Friday</div> 
<? 
} 
?> 
<? 
if( date( 'w' ) == 6 ) { 
?> 
<div>Write what you need to show here on Saturday</div> 
<? 
} 
?>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Add another condition inside each conditions to check for the time period you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the am and pm and think in 24 hours.

```
if (date('w') == 1) {
  if (date('H') >= 0 && date('H') < 17) {
    // the thing you want on monday 0:00 (12 am) to 17:00 (5pm)
  }
}
```